# Change Eclipse formatting of one-line if statements

Tags: java, eclipse

So when I use `shift+ctrl+f` to reorganize a class I have the following happen to my one-line if statements

`if (true) doThis();`

changed to

```
if (true)
    doThis();
```

How can I make `shift+ctrl+f` auto organize to be like the first statement?

Comment: you have create your own formatter...or you can use jalopy..

Comment: i'm pretty sure there is a button or something I could do to change this and a custom formatter isn't necessary. Unless i'm mistaken. As this is the only thing I want different from the original formatter.

Comment: Actually this is suggested style for Androing development as described here: https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html but default eclipse formatting syntax provided by google is doing this single thing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more exploring it seems I can change it.

1. Open `preferences` in Eclipse
2. Expand `Java`
3. Expand `Code Style`
4. Click `Formatter`
5. Click `Edit`
6. Open Tab `Control Statement`
7. Adjust "Keep 'then' statement on line

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Eclipse Kepler (Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819) ... even after trying out different Control Statement settings it always adds a new line to one-line if statements :-/.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

1. Open your eclipse
2. Go to Window - Preferences
3. Go to Java - Code Style - Formatter
4. In Active Profile : Eclipse [built-in] choose Edit
5. Go to Control Statements tab
6. Check keep 'then' statement on same line
7. Change your Profile name
8. OK

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Window > Preferences (Windows/Linux) or Eclipse > Preferences (OS X).
2. Go to Java > Code Style > Formatter.
3. Create your own code formatter if you haven't already.
4. Go to Control Statements.
5. Check the check box that says "Keep simple 'if' on one line."
6. Hit OK.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, you might try using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (as in Ireland) It doesn't actually reformat the code, but does fix all indents and whitespaces, so it won't affect one line if statements.